# SQL Synchronization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I have done SQL synchronization. I am to execute the Query like Insert,Update,Delete and it is affecting /reflecting in another PC, but if I create a table it is not replicated in another PC. How do I create a Table that is reflected in another PC which I synchronized.

SQLProduct:MsSql Server 2008

Please help

Comment: You might want to include information about what your SQL product (Oracle, Sybase, MSSqlServer) in order to get better help.

Comment: What are you using for the DB replication?  I remember using Slony-I for PostGres replication, and I believe it had to be set up on a per-table basis, i.e. the subscription set was a list of tables, not just 'this database'.  So, maybe that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (and I asked the resident expert in replication here to confirm), you need to set up a new article/subscription when you create the new table. SQL Server will not automatically add new tables for you.

You might be able to set up a DDL trigger to do it for you, but honestly I'm not too well versed in replication to know if that's feasible or not.